# Right-justification of a column using align-regexp

Tags: regex, emacs, alignment

I try to align something using align-regexp but can't get the desired behavior.

Here's what I have at first:

```
  [21:26] <Luke-Jr> btcNeverSleeps: no
  [21:26] <dmanderson> Not if it has to wait to make it into the block
  [21:26] <btcNeverSleeps> Luke-Jr: can you develop a bit?
  [21:26] <Luke-Jr> btcNeverSleeps: Bitcoin is a currency, not an authentication system
  [21:26] <dmanderson> your user could be waiting a LONG time for 1 Satoshi to who up
  [21:26] <Luke-Jr> btcNeverSleeps: you can use signed messages though
```

Here's what I want:

```
  [21:26]        <Luke-Jr> btcNeverSleeps: no
  [21:26]     <dmanderson> Not if it has to wait to make it into the block
  [21:26] <btcNeverSleeps> Luke-Jr: can you develop a bit?
  [21:26]        <Luke-Jr> btcNeverSleeps: Bitcoin is a currency, not an authentication system
  [21:26]     <dmanderson> your user could be waiting a LONG time for 1 Satoshi to who up
  [21:26]        <Luke-Jr> btcNeverSleeps: you can use signed messages though
```

Here's what I get using "align-rexegp RET > RET":  (and which is NOT what I want)

```
  [21:26] <Luke-Jr        > btcNeverSleeps: no
  [21:26] <dmanderson     > Not if it has to wait to make it into the block
  [21:26] <btcNeverSleeps > Luke-Jr: can you develop a bit?
  [21:26] <Luke-Jr        > btcNeverSleeps: Bitcoin is a currency, not an authentication system
  [21:26] <dmanderson     > your user could be waiting a LONG time for 1 Satoshi to who up
  [21:26] <Luke-Jr        > btcNeverSleeps: you can use signed messages though
```

can what I want be done with a simple `align-regexp` or should I look into something more advanced? (for example I know I can definitely do it using a macro but I'd first like to know if it can be done using a simple regexp).

Comment: I don't know emacs regex routines. But, the alignment your looking for requires a full parse of the source before the new source can be written with the correct alignment offset. Try `<[^>]*>`, don't know what `RET` is.

Comment: @sln: 'RET' is simply a convention used in Emacs docs and here on SO meaning "at that point hit the Return key" : )    (you can see some nicely formatted in one of the answer below)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `align-regexp` function is not well documented.  What you actually want to do in this case is to use C-u M-x align-regexp

Then, follow the prompts being sure to enter -1 to justify the capture group.

Complex align using regexp: `(<[^>]*>)`

Parenthesis group to modify (justify if negative): `-1`

Amount of spacing (or column if negative): 1

Repeat throughout line? (yes or no): yes

Comment: thanks, excellent... Sadly I can't upvote anyone because I miss 5 reputation points ; (

Comment: +1 for `The align-regexp function is not well documented.`  I'd love to see some documentation for this that didn't assume I was familiar with its internals.

Answer (score 4):

You need to include the bracketed text in the capturing group, then turn on justification by supplying a *negative* group argument:

<kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>M-x</kbd>`align-regexp`<kbd>RET</kbd>`\( <[^>]+>\)`<kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>DEL</kbd>`-1`<kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>`n`

`align-regexp` is definitely one of the more cryptic Emacs commands.  Powerful, though.

Comment: I kinda knew it was going to be possible using *align-regexp*. I'll still need to study that one that said : )

Answer (score 3):

You can transform the 3rd text sample into the 2nd using
`replace-regexp` with `<\([^ ]+\)\( +\)` and `\2<\1`.

Comment: ah, can't upvote you: not enough rep (need 15 rep).  Yup indeed, that's nice.  But what about doing it in one pass with *align-regexp*, is it doable?

Comment: Probably not. Even if it is, it's much easier to wrap the call to align-regexp and replace-regexp in a single function. No paramaters or confirmations or prefix arguments.